# Can anyone recommend a way for me to deploy a titanium alloy iOS app as an executable for others to preview?

Tags: ios, deployment, executable, titanium-alloy

I am looking for a solution where I have built an iOS app in titanium alloy and I would like to share it with my business owners in another state. I am looking for a way to create an executable so they can preview it before deploying it to the app store.

Is this possible? If so how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured one way of doing it.

1. must have UDID's of all the devices you would like to distribute to.
2. go to: Apple Developer Member Center,  navigate to provisioning profile.
3. add the phones/UDID's to the profile.
4. In Ti Studio 3, right click your project > run as > run configurations.
5. Under Titanium iOS Devices select your driver as iTunesSync, then select your new provisioning profile. then run your build.
6. after it syncs to iTunes, right click on your app and click 'show in finder'.
7. copy the .ipa application file and then you can distribute to your users. the app will only work on the devices that you provided UDID's for. The end user must also import the .ipa file to their iTunes to 'sync' to their phone/device.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Deploying_to_iOS_devices

Answer (score 0):

No. The app can only run in the simulator or on an actual iDevice. You could run it on your Mac in the simulator and do a screen record over the simulator, making a demo vide of the app?